# Finding Left and Right Inverses

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, solution-verification, inverse

Self learning Linear Algebra I am having some difficulty in understanding left and right inverses of a given algebraic operation. So the operation is $x\circ y=x^y$ for all positive numbers.
In order to find the inverses I have split the operation into 2 separate equations of form
$a\circ u=b$ and $v\circ a=b$ and solving $u$ and $v$ for some $a$ and $b$ from the set of positive numbers. This approach gave me right inverse as $\log_xy$ and left inverse as $x\sqrt{y}$. Is this solution correct?

Comment: This is not clear.  First of all, there's nothing "linear" here.  Secondly, you need to be clear about which element you are inverting.  if we take $x*\log_xy$ we get $x^{\log_xy}=y$  Is that what you intended?  Generally, an "inverse" should take an element to the identity.  Here?  Well, what identity element did you have in mind?

Comment: So, the first question is what is the identity.  Well, we do have that $x^1=x$ for all $x$ so $1$ is at least a "right-identity"... How about a "left identity".  Do we have a specific individual value $a$ such that $a^y=y$ is true for all values of $y$ irrespective of what $y$ is?  Suppose $y=1$ then we know that $a^1$ would have to equal $1$, meaning $a=1$... but suppose $y=2$ then we would have $a^2=2$ but $1^2$ is not equal to two...  There is no "left-identity."  If there was an identity it should have been the same for both right and left, but that is not the case here.

Comment: The punchline here is that the operation you chose is not one that lets you ask questions about inverses, and that is fine.  There are many operations where inverses don't exist.

Comment: @Lulu I missed the identity factor. Thanks.

Comment: @JMoravitz Great approach to solving inverses. Thanks. So the take away is anything that gives is right identity is right inverse and left identity left inverse. Am I right ?

Answer (score 2):

This question is a bit more tricky than you'd think at first glance, like the comments alreads mention that there is no neutral element.  And also the operation is not associative.

So what's the definition of a right-inverse? Let's define the right inverse of $x\circ y$ to be the value $a$ that "undoes" the right operand, i.e. let $a=a(y)$ be such that

$$(x\circ y)\circ a = x\tag 1$$

Using the definition of $\circ$ as power:

$$(x\circ y)\circ a = (x^y)^a = x^{ya} \stackrel!=x\tag 2$$
so that we must have $a=1/y$.

---

Likewise, let the left-inverse of $x\circ y$ be the value $b=b(x)$ such that

$$b\circ(x\circ y) = y\tag 3$$

Using the definition: $b\circ(x\circ y) = b^{(x^y)} \stackrel!= y$
then apply $x^y$-th root:

$$b = y^{1/x^y}=y^{x^{-y}}\tag 5$$

So $b$ would be a function of $x$ **and** $y$, and $b(x,y)\neq b(x)$, i.e. $b$ is not a function of $x$ alone so that a left-inverse does not exist.

Comment: Isn't right inverse something that undoes left operand to give identity as result. ?

Comment: @Meeran Mohideen: Problem is that there is nothing like neutral element because it's not a group; the operation isn't even assiciative... So I took the shortening rule as a basis. But as the author forged the question on his own, it might not make 100% sense to begin with.

Comment: Does that mean only Groups can have inverses ?

Comment: @Meeran Mohideen: No, but without a neutral element, like in the present case, one can try to establish a cancellation rule, which I did. In some sense $1$ is a right-neutral element because $x^1=x$ for all $x$'s in question, and this matches that the right-inverse as defined above is the multiplicative inverse of $y$. This doesn't help with the left side, though.

Comment: So this operation does have a right inverse atleast then.